# Float to int number conversion in c++

Tags: c++, int

The following C++ code:

```
union float2bin{

        float f;
        int i;
    };

    float2bin obj;
    obj.f=2.243;
    cout<<obj.i;
```

gives output as some garbage value .

But

```
union float2bin{

        float f;
        float i;
    };

    float2bin obj;
    obj.f=2.243;
    cout<<obj.i;
```

gives output same as the value of f i.e `2.243`

Compiler GCC has int & float of same size i.e 4 but then what's the reason behind this output behaviour?

Comment: the representation of ints and floats is different even if they're the same size...what are you expecting to see?

Comment: This is UB. Where did you read that conversions could be done with unions?

Comment: @Borgleader Are you sure? Aren't you confusing this with aliasing through incompatible pointer types?

Comment: I want to do convert float to int. I read "union" approach to do the task. Isn't it possible?

Comment: I believe Borgleader is right. It's UB to write to one union value and read from a different one.

Comment: @djadmin `float f = 3.14; int i = f;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because it is undefined behavior.  In practice,
you'll get away with reading an `int` from something that was
stored as a `float` on most machines, but you'll read garbage
values unless you know what to expect.  Doing it in the other
direction will likely cause the program to crash for certain
values of `int`.

Under the hood, of course, integral values and floating point
values have different representations, at least on most
machines.  (On some Unisys mainframes, your code *would* do what
you expect.  But they're not the most common systems around, and
you probably don't have one on your desktop.)  Basically,
regardless of the type, you have a sequence of bits, which will
be interpreted by the hardware in some way.  C++ requires
integers to use a pure binary representation, which constrains
the representation somewhat.  It also requires a very large
range for floating point values, and more or less requires some
form of exponential notation, with some bits representing the
exponent, and others the mantissa.  With different encodings for
each.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because floating point values are stored in a more complicated way, partitioning the 32 bits into a sign, an exponent and a fraction. If these bits are read as an integer straight off, it will look like a very different value.

The important point here is that if you create a union, you are saying that it is one contiguous block of memory that can be interpreted in two different ways. No where in this mechanism does it account for a safe conversion between float and int, in which case some kind of rounding occurs.

Update: What you might want is

```
float f = 10.25f;
int i = (int)f;
// Will give you i = 10
```

However, the union approach is closer to this:

```
float f = 10.25f;
int i = *((int *)&f);
// Will give you some seemingly arbitrary value
```

Comment: This is C++, prefer `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: You're right. However, in this instance I think it might hurt the instructional value of the examples, which is why I went with C-style casts.